# HDFql Get Size of Group

Tags: hdf5, hdfql

I am wondering how to get the number of datasets within a group using C++ and HDFql. Currently I have tried something like this (inspired by the HDFql manual):

```
char script[1024];
uint64_t group_size = 0;
sprintf(script, "SHOW my_group SIZE INTO MEMORY %d", HDFql::variableTransientRegister(&group_size));
HDFql::execute(script);
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work at all.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to solve your issue is to retrieve all the datasets stored in, e.g., group `my_group` like this:

```cpp
HDFql::execute("SHOW DATASET my_group/");
```

And then, get the number of datasets found using HDFql function `cursorGetCount` (which returns the number of elements in the cursor). Example:

```cpp
std::cout << "Number of datasets: " << HDFql::cursorGetCount();
```

As a side note, if you wish to retrieve all the datasets stored in group `my_group` and in sub-groups do the following (the `LIKE` option activates recursive search in HDFql):

```cpp
HDFql::execute("SHOW DATASET my_group/ LIKE **");
```

For more information, please refer to HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) and [quick start](http://www.hdfql.com/quickstart).